# Running a task at a specific time using postDelayed

Tags: android, runnable, postdelayed

I would like to start a task at a specific time. For that I use `runnable` and `postDelayed` method as follows:

```
private Runnable mLaunchTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            try {
                MY TASK
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
};
```

In my code I use `mLunchTask` as follows:

```
mHandler = new Handler();
mHandler.postDelayed(mLaunchTask, myDelay*1000);
```

and `myDelay` is computed as follows:

```
s  = DateFormat.format("hh:mm:ss aaa", d.getTime());
cTime = s.toString(); // current Time
ch = Integer.parseInt(cTime.substring(0,2)); // current hour
cm = Integer.parseInt(cTime.substring(3,5)); // current minute
cs = Integer.parseInt(cTime.substring(6,8)); // current second
if (cTime.substring(9,11).equalsIgnoreCase("pm") && (ch<12) ) ch = ch+12; 
myDelay=(desiredHour-ch)*3600+(desiredMinute-cm)*60 - cs;
if (myDelay<0) myDelay = 0;
```

and `desiredHour` and `desiredMinute` are set by user. The expectation is that `MY TASK` starts at `desiredHour` and `desiredMinute` and 0 seconds.
However "MY TASK starts with a few seconds delay, which looks like is random.

Based on the above code, is there any reason that it does not start at the exact desired time?

Thanks

Comment: Ah, mLunchTask: My favourite :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, your delay calculation is correct, but the "pm" detection doesn't work with other languages. It is much better to use the calendar to get the delay:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
long currentTimestamp = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, desiredHour);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, desiredMinute);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
long diffTimestamp = calendar.getTimeInMillis() - currentTimestamp;
long myDelay = (diffTimestamp < 0 ? 0 : diffTimestamp);
```

Now you have the delay in milli secs and can start the handler:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(mLaunchTask, myDelay);
```

In my test the following runnable logs at the desired time with no delay.

```
private Runnable mLaunchTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        Log.d("test", "started at " 
            + calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + " " 
            + calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + " "
            + calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND)
        );
    }
};
```

Maybe your started task needs some seconds to be loaded?

Could the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) be an alternative?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My task is not a heavy task and shall start right away. However, your suggestion to look into AlarmManager is a good suggestion and I should be able to use that.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience and reading of the documentation, postDelayed is based on uptime, not real time. If the phone goes into deep sleep, it can cause real time to pass without uptime incrementing. That means your task will start later than desired.

The Handler really seems to be designed for updating the GUI in an active activity, not scheduling tasks far in the future. As scessor said, AlarmManager is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

The Naliba's answer is not completely correct.

Based on  documentation that can be seen [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postAtTime%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29)
it can be seen that this class is specifically used for running tasks in the future.

*"There are two main uses for a Handler: (1) **to schedule messages and runnables to be executed as some point in the future**; and (2) to enqueue an action to be performed on a different thread than your own. "*

There is no reference about the behavior of the application when the system enters in sleep mode and this issue should be tested before posting additional information.

Comment: My answer is correct; the google documentation was just really bad at the time we wrote our posts. They improved it at some point by linking to the definition of uptimeMillis.